# Select a table and join 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 table, book table is primary table, female and male are secondary, I need join second and third by first by conditional.

example book:

```
+------+---------+----------+
| b_id | b_title | b_author |
+------+---------+----------+
|    1 | First   |        3 |
|    2 | Second  |        1 |
|    3 | Third   |       -4 |
|    4 | test    |       -3 |
+------+---------+----------+
```

male:

```
+------+--------+
| m_id | m_name |
+------+--------+
|    1 | John   |
|    2 | Jim    |
|    3 | Jessy  |
|    4 | Mike   |
|    5 | Tom    |
+------+--------+
```

female:

```
+------+--------+
| f_id | f_name |
+------+--------+
|    1 | Sarah  |
|    2 | Shanon |
|    3 | Nina   |
|    4 | Shina  |
|    5 | Mary   |
+------+--------+
```

Now I need select from book and when the b_author is positive select from male table and where the b_author select from female table.

```
SELECT b_id,b_title, IF(b_author > 0,m_name,f_name) AS 'b_author' FROM book -- how make join here.
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: More importantly, this is a terrible way to format your database. Why not just have an 'author' table with a column that specifies male or female? Then with one foreign key (in this case author_id) you could easily JOIN the tables together.

Comment: @ahjohnston25 I can't use another table, because the table designed before me in the company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from book b
left join male m on m.m_id=b.b_author
left join female f on f.f_id=b.b_author*-1
```